# Download Google Play app as APK to sdcard

Tags: android, google-play

My Android application need to be able to download some app from Google Play to sdcard. I  am not talking about installation of an application from Google Play, but rather just downloading APK.

And I am looking for API which can do this in either

- Android
- Google Play web API

Comment: There is no legitimate reason to do this.

Comment: You should also be looking for qualified legal counsel.

Comment: @adamp, what about saving old versions of apps, to be able to revert to any version you like?  If you don't like developers trying to do stuff like this, I'd recommend you talk to some of the people you work with, and let them know that it's silly that the Google Play market doesn't implement such a feature itself.  *Maybe* you can argue that Apple can get away with that, since they actually perform some quality assurance on apps they sell.  Since Google Play is choc full of garbage, many users express an interest in being able to install old app versions.